# Using float char(as operator) float in a single cout line. C++

Tags: c++, variables, char, operator-keyword

I am trying to practice c++ by doing a calculator project. I was able to successfully
accomplish the goal, but I think there is a way to simplify my 4 if statements. The fifth
if state I want to do what the other 4 do in one line. I get an error for not having
';' after the variables in the final part of cout.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float first ;
    float last ;
    char op ;

    cout << "Pick your first number.\n";
    cin>>first;
    cout << "Now pick your operator.\n";
    cin>> op;
    cout << "Time for the last number.\n";
    cin>>last;

//  if (op =='*'){ cout << first << op << last << "=" << first * last; };
//  if (op =='/'){ cout << first << op << last << "=" << first / last; };
//  if (op =='+'){ cout << first << op << last << "=" << first + last; };
//  if (op =='-'){ cout << first << op << last << "=" << first - last; };

    if (op){ cout << first << op << last << "=" << first op last; }

    char f;
    cin >> f;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: YOu can't really do this in c++, even you do that would be not portable.

Comment: You can simplify your code by using a switch statement and separating the `cout<<first<<op<<last<<'='` from printing the result (because the former is the same for all operators).

Comment: @tomriddle_1234 is on the money. C++ doesn't allow for substituting in the operator of your choice based on a variable. It isn't like interpreted languages where you can build up a string and then `exec` it.

Answer (score 0):

Although technically @tomriddle_1234 is correct you cant do a kind of scripting result, you can however to the calculation first and ensure you only have one line doing the output, something like:

```
    float result
    // this can also be implemented using switch
    if (op == '*') {
      result = first * last;
    } else if (op == '/')
      result = first / last;
    // continue for other operators

     if (op){ cout << first << op << last << "=" << result; }
```

That will at least reduce repetition a bit more.

Comment: Also you should add some checking for divide by zero :)